# What is the sum of the series $S = 1+\dfrac15+\dfrac{1\cdot 3}{5\cdot 10}+\dfrac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{5\cdot 10\cdot 15}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

The numerator is the sum of increasing AP being multiplied--> 1 3 5 7 and the denominator is multiple of 5 increasing with each term. Unable to understand how to approach this question.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.